# Cloudflare map path to domain

Tags: cloudflare

Is there a way for Cloudflare to map a requested URI to a domain that it fetches the content from?

I'd like all requests to mydomain.com/media/images to be fetched from say, bucket-name.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/media/images (and till be cached by Cloudflare)

Comment: Surprised to see some downvotes on this .. seems like a reasonable question put succinctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, is the short answer.

There isn't any way via DNS to map a sub folder to a different origin.

You could use a subdomain that points at your S3 bucket though. images.example.com instead of example.com/images that's completely possible, and is documented in our knowledge base.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it was a long shot. I could do it programatically or with an Nginx rule or something but figured if Cloudflare had a way to do it, why reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like as of July 2017 there **IS** a way now to achieve this: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/206190798-Using-Resolve-Override-in-Page-Rules

> The ability to override the URL or IP where a request resolves to is now available in Page Rules. This is an **Enterprise feature only**.
>
> A common use case for this functionality is when you are serving an application from the URI (e.g. mydomain.com/app). In this case the 'app' may live on another server and may even be hosted by a third party. Requests to this endpoint must be directed to the server for that third party application. You can specify a CNAME host.
>
> Important: the CNAME record must exist within the Cloudflare DNS.